# How can i make code split redux in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a nextjs application, and I want to code split my reducers per page, meaning that I only want that my page bundle only contain the necessary reducers.

Can someone explain to me how can I achieve this?
I already tried the following packages:

- [redux-dynamic-modules](https://github.com/Microsoft/redux-dynamic-modules/tree/master/packages) I only managed to dispatch in the client side, and I want to use the nextjs method `getInitialProps` to be able to call the first dispatch.
- [redux-dynostore](https://github.com/ioof-holdings/redux-dynostore) The client side redux state does not correctly update, and only have the default values. while the server side has the correct values.

Can someone give me a proper example of how to do this using nextjs?